# WCF Data Services GUI performance and filtering with ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, wcf-data-services

I have simple test (WPF - MVVM) client (for WCF oData service) app:

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyEntities context;

    public ICollectionView Collection { get; private set; }

    private string searchString = "";
    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return searchString; }
        set
        {
            searchString = value;
            Collection.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        context = new MyEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:3780/Live.svc"));

        Collection = new CollectionView(context.Clients);
        //Collection = new CollectionView(context.Clients.ToArray());

        Collection.Filter = (o) => (o as Client).FullName.ToString().StartsWith(SearchString);
    }
}
```

and **View**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I have two questions:

1. Why the movement of the ListBox slider slows down S_O___M_U_C_H (I
   have only 40 clients in the collection)?
2. Why, if I change this

   ```
   Collection = new CollectionView(context.Clients);
   ```

   to this

   ```
   Collection = new CollectionView(context.Clients.ToArray());
   ```

   so to break "connection" with the context through IEnumerable shell
   (it helps with UI performance problems) - stops working filtering! I
   do not understand why the disconnection of the collection from data
   context damage the filtering...

So, my final question is - is it possible to avoid GUI performance problems and at the same time implement filtering? And if so, how?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guys, I solved my problem. I should just pay attention to the message In the VS **Output** window:

*Using CollectionView directly is not fully supported.  The basic features work, although with some inefficiencies, but advanced features may encounter known bugs.  Consider using a derived class to avoid these problems.*

### The solution was simple:

I changed this

```
Collection = new CollectionView(context.Clients);
```

to this

```
Collection = new ListCollectionView(context.Clients.ToList());
```

and then there are no GUI performance problems and filtering works as expected!

### The result code was:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyEntities context;

    public ICollectionView Collection { get; private set; }

    private string searchString = "";
    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return searchString; }
        set
        {
            searchString = value;
            Collection.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        context = new MyEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:3780/Live.svc"));

        Collection = new ListCollectionView(context.Clients.ToList());

        Collection.Filter = (o) => (o as Client).FullName.ToString().StartsWith(SearchString);
    }
}
```

and **View:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />  
</Grid>
```

**WCF Data Service:**

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;

    config.UseVerboseErrors = true; 
}
```

Comment: That's not at all what I'd have expected - is it a code base you can share?

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT I added a little more code. Now better? :)